# rpy2: load R version installed in conda environment, not the one in the system

Tags: python, r, conda, rpy2

I'm using [rpy2](https://pypi.org/project/rpy2/) to run some `R` code from within a Python script. The script is run from within a `conda` environment which contains `R` version 3.6.1 installed.

The problem is that when I run the script `rpy2` loads the `R` installed in the *system* (i.e., not in the environment) which is an older version 3.4.4. I check the loaded version like this:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
r("""cat(paste("R version: ",R.version.string))""")
```

How can I force `rpy2` to use the R version installed in the `conda` environment?

---

Add

I removed the system's version of R, and now trying to run the above lines results in:

```
ValueError: r_home is None. Try python -m rpy2.situation
```

Running `python -m rpy2.situation` which shows this:

```
rpy2 version:
3.3.5
Python version:
3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
Looking for R's HOME:
    Environment variable R_HOME: None
    Calling `R RHOME`: /home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/R
    Environment variable R_LIBS_USER: None
R's additions to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

R version:
    In the PATH: R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
    Loading R library from rpy2: OK
Additional directories to load R packages from:
None
C extension compilation:
  include:
  ['/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/R/include']
  libraries:
  ['R', 'pcre', 'lzma', 'bz2', 'z', 'rt', 'dl', 'm', 'icuuc', 'icui18n']
  library_dirs:
  ['/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib', '/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib', '/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/R/lib']
  extra_compile_args:
  []
  extra_link_args:
  ['-Wl,--export-dynamic', '-fopenmp', '-Wl,-O2', '-Wl,--sort-common', '-Wl,--as-needed', '-Wl,-z,relro', '-Wl,-z,now', '-Wl,--disable-new-dtags', '-Wl,--gc-sections', '-Wl,-rpath,/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib', '-Wl,-rpath-link,/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib', '-Wl,-rpath-link,/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib']
```

which would appear to show that `rpy2` is aware of the `R` installed in `conda`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the link to the R installation to use is made during the installation of rpy2.

To use the specific R installation you mentionned I guess you can do the following steps:

- uninstalling rpy2
- adding the `bin` folder of the R installation targeted in the PATH environnement variable :
  `export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/conda/R-3.6.1/bin/`
- setting the R_HOME variable environnement to the folder of the R installation targeted:
  `export R_HOME=/path/to/conda/R-3.6.1/`
- installing rpy2 again.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I removed R from the system and although `rpy2` sees  the `R` in `conda`, the `Environment variable R_HOME` is `None`. Do you think it is necessary to remove `rpy2`?

Comment: Indeed, I guess I was partly wrong in my answer ! Did you try to manually set the R_HOME environnement variable before importing rpy2 ?

Comment: I ended up following all of your instructions. It now works if I run the script from the terminal, but still fails running from Sublime's REPL which is *very* odd. In any case, your answer was correct, so thank you!